# Alternatives to Nextion display

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, library, display, tft

I am wanting to have a display where I can design the GUI on a program and then somehow transfer it to the display. For the graphics I want to make, it would be really hard to manually write the code. I heard that the Nextion displays do this but they are quite costly. Is there some cheaper alternative? If not, can you make a normal display do all of that?

Comment: The only other make I know are 4D Systems, and they are just as much, if not more, than Nextion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We work with [Proculus](https://proculustech.en.alibaba.com/) displays, and we are a distributor of this display here in Brazil ([Victor Vision](https://victorvision.com.br/)). The display is great, very professional. Used in medical equipments, and cheaper than Nextion.
They are starting now in the web and selling in Alibaba.